# How to root Mi TV 4A?

Tags: google-play-store, 6.0-marshmallow, root-access, android-tv

I tried all rooting technique but nothing is working

Problem no 1: I can't use USB debugging options (don't have USB to USB cable) but I can able to use adb over network after boot.

Tried all kinds of apps: Kingroot, Towelroot, Kingo root.
Nothing is working ☹️

I have a useless recovery mode (because of USB to USB cable, I cannot connect).

- Tv model: Mi TV 4A
- Android: 6.0.1
- No Gapps

Have suitable TWRP & need to install TV Gapps.

Note: It's not a TV box.

[image: IMG:]